# Check if adjacent grid coordinates has an ellipse contained uwp

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am starting to build a peg solitaire game with visual studio uwp.
I have the board and pieces displaying from c# side of the xaml app.
I'm at the stage for checking if the adjacent square around the clicked ball has an ellipse contained within it.

I have the squares highlighted for testing if the correct squares are being selected when the ball is clicked. I am going to remove the highlighted squares when i figure out how to access adjacent squares and check if a ball exists in it or not.

[image]

[image]

The problem i'm having is how to check the adjacent squares if they contain an ellipse or not.

I have tried getting the name of the border and checking if it has a child element but it doesn't seem to be outputting anything when i print it out to the console.
Please see below for the mainPage.xaml.cs and mainPage.xaml files.
I' new to uwp so help that you can give would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x409

namespace Solitaire
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {

        public MainPage()
        {

            this.InitializeComponent();

            addRowsColumns();
            addBorders();
            addPieces();
        }
        private void addRowsColumns()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            {
                grdGame.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
                grdGame.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
            }

        }


        private void addBorders()
        {
            Border brdr;
            int iR, iC;

            //iR set to 1 to center the board in front of the background
            for (iR = 1; iR < 8; iR++)
            {//iC set to 1 to center board
                for (iC = 1; iC < 8; iC++)
                {
                    brdr = new Border();
                    //name for getting the position of the peices on the board.
                    brdr.Name = "square_" + iR.ToString() + "_" + iC.ToString();
                    //set default colour of border to balck
                    brdr.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);

                    // if modulus of iR + iC is 0, then make the square white
                    if ((iR + iC) % 2 == 0)
                    {
                        brdr.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);

                    }
                    //remove the squares that are not needed for the game
                    //colour these squares the same colour as the grid background
                    //@todo need to make these references in the grid non playable.
                    if ((iR<3&&iC <3)||(iR <3  && iC > 5)|| (iR >5 && iC < 3) || (iR >5 && iC > 5))
                    {
                        brdr.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.BurlyWood);
                    }
                    brdr.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, iR);
                    brdr.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, iC);
                    brdr.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
                    brdr.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
                    //@todo set height and width of squares not hard coded.
                    brdr.Height = 100;
                    brdr.Width = 100;
                  //add squares to the board.

                    grdGame.Children.Add(brdr);


                }

            }
        }
        int _Rows = 8;

        private void addPieces()
        {
            Ellipse myEl;
            int iR, iC;
            // use R&C to name the objects
            for (iR = 1; iR < _Rows; iR++)
            {
                for (iC = 1; iC < _Rows; iC++)
                {//center square no elipse set for the opening move
                    if (!((iR < 3 && iC < 3) 
                        || (iR < 3 && iC > 5) 
                        || (iR > 5 && iC < 3) 
                        || (iR > 5 && iC > 5)
                        ||(iR==4&&iC==4)))
                    {
                        myEl = new Ellipse();
                        myEl.Name = "el_" + iR + "_" + iC;
                        myEl.Tag = "peices";
                        myEl.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Silver);
                        myEl.Height = 40;
                        myEl.Width = 40;
                        myEl.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, iR);
                        myEl.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, iC);

                        myEl.Tapped += myEl_Tapped;
                        grdGame.Children.Add(myEl);


                    }

                }

            }

        }



        private void myEl_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Ellipse moveMe;
            Border possible1, possible2, possible3, possible4;
            int toR1,toC1;
            Ellipse current = (Ellipse)sender;

            Debug.WriteLine(current.Name);
            moveMe = current;
            //current.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);

            toR1 = (int)current.GetValue(Grid.RowProperty);
           // toR2 = (int)current.GetValue(Grid.RowProperty); 

            toC1 = (int)current.GetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty);
            //brdr1 = (int)brdr.GetValue(Grid.RowProperty);

            //toC2 = (int)current.GetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty);
            //Print out rows and coloums one above and below, one to left and right.
            Debug.WriteLine("Move row 1 : "+toR1+" MOve col 1: "+toC1);

            possible1 = new Border();
            possible2 = new Border();
            possible3 = new Border();
            possible4 = new Border();
            possible1.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, toR1);
            possible1.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, toC1+1);
            possible2.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, toR1);
            possible2.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, toC1 - 1);
            possible1.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gold);
            possible2.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gold);
            possible3.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, toR1+1);
            possible3.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, toC1);
            possible4.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, toR1-1);
            possible4.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, toC1);
            possible3.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gold);
            possible4.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gold);
            grdGame.Children.Add(possible1);
            grdGame.Children.Add(possible2);
            grdGame.Children.Add(possible3);
            grdGame.Children.Add(possible4);
        }



        //@todo add tapped event to peices and move them no logic for now

    }

}
```

And the xaml file

```
<Page
x:Class="Solitaire.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Solitaire"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid x:Name="grdGame">




</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is a single method to ease the pain of searching for a neighbor:**

- assuming you use a `Grid` where each child takes exactly 1 row and 1 column
- all of the childs are hooked to the same clicked event
- the method will return a `bool` and the element found, if any

**TODO:**

When an element is returned, further check according your condition, for instance, you could set and check the `Tag` property of the `Button`.

[image]

XAML:

```
<Window
    x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Click="Button_Click" />
        <Button
            Grid.Row="2"
            Grid.Column="2"
            Click="Button_Click" />
        <Button
            Grid.Row="2"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Click="Button_Click" />
        <Button
            Grid.Row="2"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Click="Button_Click" />
        <Button
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="2"
            Click="Button_Click" />
        <Button
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="2"
            Click="Button_Click" />
        <Button
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Click="Button_Click" />
        <Button
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Click="Button_Click" />
        <Button
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Click="Button_Click" />

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var button = (Button) sender;

            // where is the element you want, relative row/column to this one
            var relativeX = 1;
            var relativeY = 1;

            UIElement result;

            if (TryGetAdjacent(button, relativeX, relativeY, out result))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Yes !");

                // TODO further check whether element satisfies some condition
            }
        }

        private bool TryGetAdjacent(Button button, int relativeX, int relativeY, out UIElement result)
        {
            result = null;

            var row = Grid.GetRow(button);
            var col = Grid.GetColumn(button);

            var parent = (Grid) button.Parent;
            var rows = parent.RowDefinitions.Count;
            var cols = parent.ColumnDefinitions.Count;


            var x = row + relativeX;
            var y = col + relativeY;
            if (x < 0 || x >= cols || y < 0 || y >= rows)
                return false;

            foreach (var child in parent.Children.Cast<UIElement>())
            {
                var col1 = Grid.GetColumn(child);
                var row1 = Grid.GetRow(child);

                if (row1 != x || col1 != y)
                    continue;

                result = child;
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE:**

Sorry, I don't have UWP at hand so this is WPF, it should work out of the box since the logic is quite similar. You might have to do little adjustments but all in all, you'll get the point of my simplified approach.